# How can i deploy Microsoft.Web/staticSites code using zipdeploy file?

Tags: azure-rm-template, azure-managed-app

We're working on ARM template for the Managed Application.
The app has to contain a web portal for users to interact with.
For this purposes we've decided to use "Site" and "StaticSite" azure resources.
There's a documentation regarding deploying a "Site" using "zipdeploy" and we have no problems with it.
However, we haven't found zipdeloy ARM instructions for the StaticSite resource.

How can i deploy StaticSite code using zip archive ?